# Redirecting to another page via a json call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm using the [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) utility in my app.  If I have some code like the following normally in rails...

```
if @course_module.save
  flash[:success] = "Class created!"
  redirect_to course_course_modules_path(@course)
else
  render 'new'
end
```

It will display error messages if there are errors in my form, or redirect to another page if it saved successfully.  But this is not so when the page is submitted through the jquery
plugin.  The reason is it requires a json object to be returned....something like

```
         format.json {  
          render ':json => [@course_module.to_jq_upload].to_json ' 
        }
```

How would I instead of returning json, do the first code snippet instead?  Either by redirecting if the save is successful, or display error messages if it is not?  I've tried something like the following...

```
render 'new'
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/banditj/fily/blob/no-asset-pipeline/app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb). It's an example from the Wiki page of the Jquery file upload github repo.

Answer (score 0):

The normal ajax call has a success and error methods, just add to the json response a redirect_url key having the path you want to go to as the value and inside the success method redirect to this url.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: '/path to your controller',
 datatype: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
   window.location.href = data.redirect_url
 };

});
```

and your json response should look like this inside the controller

```
render :json => {course_module: @course_module.to_jq_upload, redirect_url: course_course_modules_path(@course) }.to_json
```

I hope that's what you are looking for